# Copy/move value of note to another note

Tags: xml, xslt

We have a scanning software which create an XML file with document information for each page scanned. The software also has an xslt post-process that can be used with our own scripts.

We need a script that can move or copy the value from the `<AnnString></AnnString>` to `<PreIJP></PreIJP>` for each page.

I do have some programming expirience, but I do not have any expirience with xslt.
I've tried to figure it out, without luck.

[The XML input](http://pastebin.com/gCCuMpHG)

And here is the code i've tried to use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Page/Fields/AnnString/text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="../../PreIJP"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Best Regards,
Jesper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it backwards (among other issues). Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PreIJP">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="../AnnString"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to populate the empty `PreIJP` elements then change

```
<xsl:template match="Page/Fields/AnnString/text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="../../PreIJP"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="PreIJP">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="../AnnString"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```